# Set particular bibliography field to italics and single spacing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, annotations

I am trying to use

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions
```

to make the [addendum] field both in italics and single-spaced. However, {font=textit} and {space=double}/{spacing=double}/{space=doublespace}/{spacing=doublespace} do not seem to work.

What is the correct 'key' and 'value' format for both italicizing and making single space?

Current code:

```
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Phi-Features and Animacy.bib}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
    {}
    {\bibhyperref{\printdate}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[addendum]{?????}
```

MWEB

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{asdfggg.bib}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[addendum]{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{addendum}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
    {}
    {\bibhyperref{\printdate}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}
    
\begin{filecontents}{asdfggg.bib}
@thesis{codename,
author = {Name Surname},
title = {Title: A Subtitle},
type = {Doctoral Dissertation},
institution = {University of Asdfg},
year = {3333},
location = {Location},
addendum = {\linebreak This is my annotation.}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\nocite{*}
\uspunctuation
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Annotated Bibliography}
]

\end{document}
```

Neither `\DeclareFieldFormat` nor `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` seem to be working for me.

Comment: Please provide a full [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).  If you want the `addendum` field to be single spaced, but everything else in your bibliography double spaced, then the `addendum` field would need to be in a paragraph on its own. Is this what you want? For making a field italic, you use the `\DeclareFieldFormat` macro, not a `key=value` system.

Comment: Hi @DavidPurton I have added a MWEB. Yes, that is the goal. Unfortunately, I have tried using \DeclareFieldFormat (see MWEB) and nothing happened. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not all of `biblatex`'s customisation features are available as key-value options. In particular field formatting is almost exclusively dealt with via `\DeclareFieldFormat`, which does not use key-value syntax, but instead works like a normal macro definition (where we can understand `\DeclareFieldFormat{<field>}{<code with #1>}` as defining a helper macro that is then applied as `\<helper macro>{<field contents>}`).

You are already using `\textit` to make the `addendum` italic, so we only need to add a command or environment that gives us single-spacing. Since you are loading `setspace` a solution could look like

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{addendum}{%
  \begin{singlespace}
    \itshape #1%
  \end{singlespace}%
  \nopunct}
```

In total

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{addendum}{%
  \begin{singlespace}
    \itshape #1%
  \end{singlespace}%
  \nopunct}

\usepackage{lipsum}
    
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{codename,
  author      = {Name Surname},
  title       = {Title},
  subtitle    = {A Subtitle},
  type        = {phdthesis},
  institution = {University of Asdfg},
  year        = {3333},
  location    = {Location},
  addendum    = {This is my annotation. \lipsum},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\uspunctuation
\printbibliography[
  heading=bibintoc,
  title={Annotated Bibliography}
]

\end{document}
```

[image: Annotation in single-space and italics.]